# Como envió el id para revivirlo en otra vista

Tags: php, html5, ajax

estoy empezando en esto de la programación y estoy un poco perdido , estoy trabajando en un formulario , ya tengo el registrar y el modificar no sé como hacerlo , ya busque por varios sitios y intento e intento y no me da , estoy trabajando con un encarpetado MVC llamado Mini3 , quiero resivir el id y con este podre llenar los campos pero no se como , solo necesito saber como resivo el id por GET en este código ya el resto lo podría realizar, Gracias por su atención.

Codigo :

```html
<td style="text-align: center"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="#" id="" onclick="Tcaso(<?=$p->id ?>)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Editar</a></td>
```

```html
<form id="formA" name="f1" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="" onsubmit="return validate2()" autocomplete="off" >

    <div class="form-group row">

      <label for="telefono" class="col-md-1 control-label">Nº Cuenta</label>
              <div class="col-md-2" autofocus disabled>
               <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm input  soloNum" id="ncuentaca" name="ncuentaca" autofocus disabled>
              </div>

              <label for="cliente" class="col-md-1 control-label">Cliente</label >
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm input" name="nombreca" id="nombreca" autofocus disabled>
              </div>

              

              
              <label for="documento" class="col-md-1 control-label">Dirección</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm input" id="direccionca" name="direccionca" autofocus disabled>
              </div>

              
              
            </div>

            <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
            
            <div class="pull-right">
                 <main class="mdl-layout__content">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="enviarca" name="enviarca">Agregar</button>
               </main>
          </div>
        </div>

        </form>
```

```js
function Tcaso(id){ 
   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data:{'id':id},
    dataType:'json',
    url: uri + "/caso/mostrarCasos",
   }).done(function(respuesta){
    $("#id").val(respuesta.id);
    $("#nombreca").val(respuesta.idcliente);
    $("#modalT").modal();

    
  
   });
  }
```

```js
public function mostrarCasos()
 {
  $id= $_POST['id'];
  if (isset($id)) {
            
   $caso = new Caso();
            
   $caso = $caso->mostrarCasos($id);

   echo json_encode($caso);
  } else {
            // redirect user to songs index page (as we don't have a id)
   echo "Error, no ingreso el id";
  }

 }
```

```js
public function mostrarCasos($id)
  {
    $sql = "SELECT id, falla, responsable,  fecha ,descripcion , seguimiento , solucion , estado , idcliente FROM caso WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $parameters = array(':id' => $id);
    $query->execute($parameters);

    return $query->fetch();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

En la funcion Tcaso() estas usando un envio POST debes cambiarlo a GET es mas facil

```
function Tcaso(id){ 
    $.get( "turuta/tuarchivo.php?idenvio="+id, function( data ) {
             //$( ".result" ).html( data );
    });
}
```

en tuarchivo.php podrias usar
$_GET['idenvio'] para recuperar lo y hacer lo que quieras
.... "data" te retorna el resultado de tuarchivo.php

Comment: Hola que pena contigo , te comento utilizo un encarpetado Mvc llamado mini3 y los url los tengo que hacer <?php echo URL ?>cliente/mostrarCasos llamando a la funcion de los controladores que estos asignan las ruta y ya probe con <?php echo URL ?>cliente/mostrarCasos?idenvio="+id" y no funciona

Comment: Especifica con imagenes y codigo lo que quieres hacer, no logro enntenderte

Comment: pudiste? entenderme

Comment: por que la verdad estaba sencillo ya lo logre solo tenia que enviarlo por get y resivirlo en mi ajax con type GET

Answer (score 0):

Para que quede más claro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es la tabla que estoy usando quiero que cuando le de click a "Editar" 
me mande a esta otra vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El input que es más pequeño es el campo donde estoy tratando de traer el id , en este caso , ya sea 1 ,2 o 3 , el código ya esta arriba , pero lo que quiero es mandar el id , tú me dices que por GET , pero como si yo uso un encarpetado MVC tengo que llamar así a mis controladores en el href , no uso archivos.php para hacer mi codificación esto se hace automáticamente mediante al controlador y este llama al modelo que hace las consultas, el resto de código esta arriba , gracias por la atención

```html
<td style="text-align: center"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="<?php echo URL ?>caso/editar" id="" onclick="Tcaso(<?=$p->id ?>)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Editar</a></td>
```

Comment: Ya encontré la solución muchas gracias por los que se interesaron por el post solo tenia que enviar la variable por post y resivirla con GET